# Is $\pi(x)$ well-approximated by an expression of the form $\frac{x}{\log(x)}(1+1/\log(x)+c/\log(x)^2)$ for some $c\in[0,2.51]$?

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers

It [is known](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime_number_theorem#Non-asymptotic_bounds_on_the_prime-counting_function) that for all $x\ge 355991$,

$$\frac{x}{\log(x)}\left(1+\frac{1}{\log(x)}\right) < \pi(x)< \frac{x}{\log(x)}\left(1 + \frac{1}{\log(x)} + \frac{2.51}{\log(x)^2}\right)$$

I am curious whether there are more precise results of this form, i.e. that $\pi(x)$ is greater than or less than $\frac{x}{\log(x)}(1 + \frac{1}{\log(x)} + \frac{c}{\log(x)^2})$ for tighter values of $c$ (perhaps dependent on the Riemann Hypothesis or other conjectures).

Is it known where there is a real constant $c$ such that

$$\lim_{x\to\infty}\left(\frac{\pi(x)\log(x)^3}{x}-\log(x)^2-\log(x)\right)=c$$

or is it possible (or even conjectured/known) that this limit does not exist? If so, what are the extant results on its liminf and limsup?

If such a constant $c$ does exist, can this sort of asymptotic behavior be extended further, to $1/\log(x)^3$ terms and so on? Are there conjectured values for these coefficients?

Empirically, at $x=10^{28}$ it seems like the right constant $c$ is around $2.099$, but the ideal constant seem to decrease as $x$ grows larger. From some crude curve-fitting, I would hazard a guess at something like $2.05$ as the limit, but very low confidence on that number.

Comment: there is an asymptotic expansion based on repeated integration by parts of the logarithmic integral function; if your intended approximation agrees with the expansion up to some order it is better that nearby guesses https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logarithmic_integral_function#Asymptotic_expansion

Comment: alright, $c=2$ is the best possible

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It can be verified using integration by parts that
$$
\int_2^x {\frac{{{\rm d}t}}{{\log t}}}  \sim \frac{x}{{\log x}}\sum\limits_{k = 0}^\infty  {\frac{{k!}}{{\log ^k x}}} 
$$
as $x\to+\infty$. In 1899, de la Vallée Poussin proved that
$$
\pi (x) = \int_2^x {\frac{{{\rm d}t}}{{\log t}}}  + \mathcal{O}\!\left( {x{\rm e}^{ - c\sqrt {\log x} } } \right) = \int_2^x {\frac{{{\rm d}t}}{{\log t}}}  + \mathcal{O}\!\left( {\frac{1}{{\log ^r x}}} \right)
$$
as $x\to+\infty$, where $c$ is a suitable positive number and $r>0$ is arbitrary. Hence,
$$
\pi (x) \sim \frac{x}{{\log x}}\sum\limits_{k = 0}^\infty  {\frac{{k!}}{{\log ^k x}}} 
$$
as $x\to+\infty$. Therefore, the constants you are after are the factorials.